# How to remove webapp name from urls in spring security

Tags: spring, apache, spring-boot, spring-security, tomcat9

I deployed my spring boot webapp to Apache Tomcat. Apache Tomcat sits behind a httpd webserver. I want to access my webapp with `www.mydomain.de`, which works fine for the most part. I achived this by using a VirtualHost with the following configuration:

```
ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8011/mywebapp/
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8011/mywebapp/
```

The webapp worked well to the point I added Spring Security authentication. When I click on a page which requires authentication, `www.mydomain.de/mywebapp/login` is loaded. I want `www.mydomain.de/login`

Heres my Spring Security configuration:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/index").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .failureUrl("/login")
                .usernameParameter("username")//
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .permitAll();
    }
```

How can I remove the webapp name in the URL?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Spring Security application to run behind a proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26526830/how-to-make-spring-security-application-to-run-behind-a-proxy)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the context path in the application.properties file. Example `server.contextPath=/`